# How do I start Firefox in another language than the default?

Tags: firefox, locale

I want to temporarily use Firefox in another languages so that menus and everything else in another language. How can I do that?

I have tried

```
firefox -no-remote -UILocale en-GB
```

but that still loads Firefox with my default locale (I have en-GB locale for Firefox installed).

I also found https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/565209 but I dunno if it's due to that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Goto menu item *Adds-On*, then *Languages* and disable the non wanted language.
You need to restart firefox, then.

Another solution: from command line:

```
LC_ALL=en_GB firefox -no-remote
```

in this way you change the environment of firefox, making it believe it is in en_GB locale, only for the given execution.

Obviously both the locale than the firefox support package for that locale should be installed, for this to work.

For example, to see `firefox` in french, the prerequisites are:

```
sudo locale-gen fr_FR fr_FR.UTF-8 && echo "Success"
sudo apt-get install firefox-locale-fr
LC_ALL=fr_FR firefox -no-remote
```

Comment: That seems like a hassle if I just want to change language temporarily.

Comment: The command line solution does not change locale permanently but only for that particular execution?

Comment: @N.N.: yes, only for that execution, in my tests

Comment: Cool, if that is so it might make sense to add that to your answer to explain the meaning of the command line solution.

Comment: @N.N.: Just one remark, this solution is firefox-independent. All locale-aware software can be executed this way.

Comment: When I try `LC_ALL=en_GB firefox -no-remote` I get "(process:19853): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library. Using the fallback 'C' locale." I have firefox-locale-en installed.

Comment: @N.N.: you should also generate the locale for `en_GB`, with `sudo locale-gen en_GB en_GB.UTF-8 && echo "Success!"`

Comment: That command returns `bash: !": event not found`.

Comment: @N.N.: sorry I have bash history substitution disabled: simply remove the `!` in the comment.

Comment: @enzotib Cheers! Now it works. Reason I asked was to make the screenshot in http://askubuntu.com/questions/63728/how-do-i-enable-the-telemetry-feature-of-firefox-7/63729#63729 in English.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install language as enzotib (+1) pointed it out first. Then you can switch between available locales.

To switching it easier, you can install addon like [quick-locale-switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quick-locale-switcher/).

You cannot switch to locale you don't have installed before. Firefox does not have all translated messages bundled in default installation. This will be unneeded waste of resources on many levels.

Comment: I have the locale I tried to switch to. I tried the addon you suggested but when I switch to a locale I have installed the language of the menus in Firefox stays the same (even after restart).

Comment: Thanks to point out the need to have the locale installed.

Comment: @N.N.: does your locale switching affect output seen on http://aruljohn.com/lang.php ?

Answer (score -1):

Download prefered language package firefox and after you should run the following commands:

sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/firefox

sudo cp -a /*root where you unzip the packagee* /usr/lib/firefox

sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/firefox

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox

Comment: These instructions do not seem to be wise.