# How do I enable submission of performance data in Firefox 7?

Tags: firefox, performance

One item in [the release notes of Firefox 7](http://www.mozilla.org/firefox/7.0/releasenotes/) reads

> Added an [opt-in system](http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/asa/archives/2011/07/telemetry_in_firefox.html) for users to send performance data back to
>   Mozilla to improve future versions of Firefox

This is feature is also called *telemetry*. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Enter the Preferences of Firefox.
2. Go to Advanced.
3. Check "Submit performance data" under General - System Defaults.

[image: How to submit performance data in Firefox]